# Unity - Phyics.Raycast returns false

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation, raycasting

I create an emtpy game object and attach .cs file. I try to load a prefab(.obj file) on mouse click position. My code is :

```
    Ray ray;
    RaycastHit hit;
    public GameObject prefab;

    void Start()
    {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            ray=Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                GameObject obj = Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(hit.point.x, hit.point.y, hit.point.z), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;

            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Physics.Raycast returns false");
            }
    }
```

Raycast returns false everytime.

Comment: What is it meant to collide with? Do you have a plane or a box with a collider attached to it?

Comment: I did `Add Component-> Box Collider

Comment: Try to add a basic cube object and extend it to make it look like a plane.It already contains the collider. Then, your raycast script on the camera for instance. Click on your cube and that should do.

Comment: ok. thanks it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add Collider to your GameObject

**For Physics3D**

> **Description**
>
> Casts a ray against all colliders in the scene.

Physics.Raycast Script API documentation [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html).

**For Physics2D**

> **Description**
>
> Casts a ray against colliders in the scene.
>
> A raycast is conceptually like a laser beam that is fired from a point
>   in space along a particular direction. Any object making contact with
>   the beam can be detected and reported.

Physics2D.Raycast Script API documentation [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html).

Comment: Òn inspector, I added box collider component.

Comment: Try it with creating new Box with Box collider. if it works, you need to specify volume (X,Y,Z size). If your object doesn't have volume you can't raycast it. And also check your collider have same volume and starts with 0,0,0 point of your Gameobject.

Comment: I am raycasting down from player to colliders my player is standing on and getting false.

Answer (score 3):

You need to attach a 3d collider to your sprite game object to get detected by raycast.

[See my complete answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54807784/6662058)