# RayCastHit2D does not detect Player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, raycasting

I am trying to cast a 2D Ray from an instantiated missile prefab as follows:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyMissile : MonoBehaviour {


    void Update () {
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.down,1f);
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, Vector2.down, Color.green);
        if(hit)
        {
            print("Hit");
        }
        else
        {
            print("No hit");
        }
    }
}
```

I can clearly see on the scene that the Ray goes through the Player:
[image]

The Player has a Rigidbody2D and a BoxCollider2D as trigger:
[image]

And the EnemyMissile has its own RigidBody2D and BoxCollider2D as trigger:
[image]

**However I see nothing printed on the console**

The idea to cast a Ray from the missile is to play an AudioClip when the EnemyMissile is going towards Player.

I have seen:
[Raycast Hit Collider is Always NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43149633/raycast-hit-collider-is-always-null)
[Physics2D.Raycast returning null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42788004/physics2d-raycast-returning-null)

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT**  to answer @Monofuse comment: When I select the Player the Transform is:
x: 0.4567, y: -1.58, z: 0

[image]

When I select the missile the Transform is:
x: 0.3699, y: -1.054, z: 0

[image]

**EDIT to answer @Ada Nub:**

I had by default both option checked: Queries Hit Triggers and Queries Start in Colliders.

Now I have unchecked Queries Start in Colliders, however the result is the same, I do not see the print on the console:

[image]

I have realized my mistake, I had the Information tab in the console not pressed:
[image]

And now it works:
[image]

Comment: Are they both on the same y axis? maybe they are colliding on the X and Z, but not on the Y.

Comment: Ah, so it was a silly mistake haha happens to the best of us :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you turned on 'Queries hit triggers' in Edit > Project Settings > Physics2D?
Raycasts by default do not hit triggers, so this may be your issue.

[Image of 'Queries hit triggers' option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXHLK.png)

The option right below it, 'Queries start in colliders', might also be worth looking into; since you're casting the raycast from inside the missile's collider, you'll probably want that option unchecked so that it doesn't count the missile it starts in as a hit.